# How to iterate over 2 scopes with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

If I have 2 scopes that share a common Person code value, can I link them in the view perhaps using ng-repeat? I suppose what I'm trying to do is something similar to nested for loops.
I'd like to iterate through one scope whilst checking the other for matching person codes and then display a different button if the person code exist in second scope.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in model.data | filter: cc.course_code | filter: occ.occurrence | filter: tgn.tutor_group_name | orderBy: 'surname'  | unique: 'PERSON_CODE'" ng-model="x">
  <h4><b>{{ x.forename }} {{x.surname}}</b>  ID: {{x.PERSON_CODE}}</h4>
  <h5>{{x.course_name}}</h5>
  <h5>{{ x.faculty_name }} {{x.area_code}}   </h5>
  <h5>{{x.area_name}}</h5>
  <h5>{{x.tutor_group_name}}</h5>
  <div ng-repeat="d in destinations.data" ng-model="d">
    <div ng-if="(x.PERSON_CODE === d.PERSON_CODE)">
      <div ng-show="d.EMP_DEST_CODE" class="pull-right">
        <a href="#myModal" type="button" class="btn btn-success butt-sz ladda-button" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="editStudent(x.PERSON_CODE);">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit Destination
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="(!d.EMP_DEST_CODE)" class="pull-right">
    <a href="#myModal" type="button" class="btn btn-warning butt-sz ladda-button" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="editStudent(x.PERSON_CODE);">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"></span> Record Destination
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried the above way but that isnt working at all right.

I would like the green button to appear if there is a corresponding entry in the destinations scope and if there is not Id like the green button displayed.

Comment: What is the issue in your code? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: @Mistalis yes sorry I edited above, the code currently applies a red button to every item, not just the ones without an entry in the destinations scope which is how i would like it to behave. So that each item only displays one button either red or green

Comment: why you are using two scope? get the data in single scope.

Comment: @Simanchal.panigrahi I did have it in one scope but whenever user saved new data  it refreshed all the the user filters which wasn't popular with users, so I split them so that saving new destination data wouldnt affect any thing else. Not sure if that was correct but Im short on ideas and under pressure to find solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to write a function in controller that checks if the passed entry is in `destinations` like this:

```
$scope.isDestination = function(p) {
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.destinations.data.length; i++) {
        if(p.PERSON_CODE == $scope.destinations.data[i].PERSON_CODE) 
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Considering this function, you can display conditionally your buttons without ng-repeating over the `destinations` array:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in model.data | filter: cc.course_code | filter: occ.occurrence | filter: tgn.tutor_group_name | orderBy: 'surname'  | unique: 'PERSON_CODE'" ng-model="x">
  ...

  <div ng-if="isDestination(x)"> <!-- isDestination returns true -->
    <a href="#myModal" type="button" class="btn btn-success butt-sz ladda-button" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="editStudent(x.PERSON_CODE);">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit Destination
    </a>
  </div>

  <div ng-if="!isDestination(x)"> <!-- isDestination returns false -->
    <a href="#myModal" type="button" class="btn btn-danger butt-sz ladda-button" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="editStudent(x.PERSON_CODE);">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"></span> Record Destination
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you that's  a great answer, I wish I could have thought of it, rather than bumbling around for so long, it works great Thanks again